How to remove or fix Autoprefixer in Sublime Text
I have been running Autoprefixer for a while and recently have started getting this error every time I save a CSS file. It's something I've found several threads on in searches but I don't have the required understanding to implement any of the fixes I have found.

Autoprefixer Error: internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172 throw new
ERR_REQUIRE_ESM(filename, parentPath, packageJsonPath); ^
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: Must use import to load ES Module:
/Users/XXXXXX/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text
3/Packages/Autoprefixer/autoprefixer.js at
Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1172:13)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1000:32) at
Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:899:14) at
Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain]
(internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12) at
internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 { code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM' }

I'd be happy to either fix this or simply remove the package altogether but even this latter is proving impossible (it isn't in the package control areas of Sublime Text like the other additions I use).
I'm sure there's an issue with the way I have installed or set up the working environment — I have exceeded my knowledge on the matter.
Can anyone please explain how I either fix this so it works as intended, or failing that simply remove it altogether?
